# Error on https configuration on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

i have applied ssl certificate on my apache web server to https support.
To do this, i have created two virtual hosts:

```
# www virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.it
    ServerName dev.example.it
    ServerAlias dev.example.it
    DocumentRoot /home/my/dev
    Redirect permanent / https://dev.example.it/
    ...
</VirtualHost>

#ssl virtual host
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/ssl/www_example_it.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/ssl/www_example_it.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/ssl/www_example_it.ca-bundle"

    ServerAdmin info@example.it
    DocumentRoot /home/my/dev
    ServerName dev.example.it
    ServerAlias dev.example.it
    ErrorLog logs/ssl.dev.example.it-error_log
    CustomLog logs/ssl.dev.example.it-access_log common
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also i have some rewrite rule on .htaccess on root of my site; something like following:

```
# user profile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user\-[a-zì_]+/[a-z0-9ü\-]+$
RewriteRule ^user-(.*)/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/profile/$2/$1/user [P]
```

i don't understand why i receive an internal server error on browser if i point to url https://www.example.it/user-par1/par2 and apache error log says:

```
[Wed Oct 05 08:42:07.163798 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 23567] [remote x.x.x.x:443] AH01961: SSL Proxy requested for dev.example.it:443 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
[Wed Oct 05 08:42:07.163834 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 23567] AH00961: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for x.x.x.x:443 (dev.example.it)
```

Anyone can help me with this problem please?

Comment: Do the errors happen only when you write a url that match the RewriteRule? All other ulrs on https are ok?

Comment: Yes, only with urlt that much RewriteRule @LuigiC. What can i do?